# Code blocks in font-lock comments

Tags: font-lock, comment, semantic-mode

I'm developing a major mode for a language that has doc comments. They look like this:

```
(** Foos three bars.
    Better call this as [foo 1 b c].
    Though of course [foo a b 1] works as well. **)
Definition foo a b c := a + b - c.
```

In that context `[` and `]` work as sorts of unescapes: anything between them is really code, not comments.

Is there a generic approach this? IOW, **is there a way to tell font-lock: in comments, treat anything between `[]` as code?**

I can see a bunch of cool applications for this beyond my major mode: for example doctests in python (where `>>>` should introduce code), or javadoc, or doxygen, etc.

```
"""Foos the bars
>>> foo 1 2 3 # should be highlighted as code
0
>>> foo 4 5 6 # should be highlighted as code
3"""
```

I considered making `[` a comment closer, and `]` a comment opener, but it looks very brittle: it will confuse navigation commands, and nested comments, and will require a strange comment setup to allow multiple closers per opener; and it won't work outside of comments, either.

Comment: In a way, all font-lock rules apply both to comments and non-comments. The fact that they isn't rendered in a comment because a normal rule don't have an OVERRIDE flag. If you add `prepend` to the rule, it will add it's highlight on top of the comment face.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Indeed; only I'm not aware of a way to make the flag conditional, i.e. make it `prepend` only in `[]` pairs in comments.

Comment: You can replace the regexp with a function, in that function you can search for the regexp using `re-search-forward` and skip those cases where the context is wrong. The answer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20222/part-ii-colorizing-functions-variables-within-comments-in-c-mode/20228#20228 does something similar (the condition in this case is that something should be highlighted in comments only).

Comment: @Lindydancer: I'm aware of this, but I don't see how it applies here; is your suggestion to duplicate all font-lock keywords and have one copy for code blocks in comments (with `'prepend` and a custom function), and another copy for regular code?

Comment: There is no need to duplicate the rules, just use the condition that the text either is outside of comments or enclosed in brackets in a comment.

Comment: @Lindydancer I don't think that works: it will require adding a `prepend` to every rule, which will break rules that already depend on `prepend` and `append`. Won't it?

Comment: Yes, that's true... I just came up with another approach. You can add a "fake" rule that removes the `font-lock-comment-face` from bracket-enclosed areas. Subsequent rules will highlight normally.

Comment: ... after giving it some thought I realised that this wasn't a good idea after all. Strings won't be highlighted, for example. OK, back to the drawing boards. What about taking your idea of making `]` a comment ender and `[` a comment start character, but implement this using a `syntax-propertize-function`, that only do this inside comments only?

Comment: @Lindydancer: That will confuse code that uses `comment-forward` and the like :/

Comment: Try doing something like what `lisp-font-lock-syntactic-face-function` does (in `lisp-mode.el`). It font-locks comments using syntactic font-lock, but it recognizes ` ... '  syntax within comments and highlights them with a different face. It sounds like you want to do that, but in your case the second highlighting is for `[...]`.

Comment: @Drew: This isn't enough: I need full-fledged highlighting, not just uniform highlighting of `[...]` blocks.

Comment: Perhaps someone else will offer a solution. Maybe @Stefan can help here.