# Part II -- Colorizing `functions/variables' within comments in `c-mode'

Tags: font-lock, c-mode

I have implemented the solution of Yasushi Shoji in a previous thread -- [Colorizing `functions/variables' within comments in `c-mode'](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20124/colorizing-functions-variables-within-comments-in-c-mode) -- to highlight Lisp function/variable names in `c-mode` **comments** that begin with a back-tick and end with a single quote:

```
/* See the doc-string for `pos-visible-in-window-p'.  */
```

The function `c-font-lock-doc-comments` unfortunately does away with the ability to highlight the comment beginning/ending with `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face`, which is a member of `c-literal-faces`.  What happens is that the entire comment (except for the function/variable) gets highlighted with `c-doc-face-name`.

The unsophisticated approach is to redefine `c-font-lock-doc-comments` by removing or commenting out the offending code:

```
(c-put-font-lock-face region-beg region-end c-doc-face-name)
```

However, doing so will break the *intended* functionality for the three (3) other forms of predefined `c-doc-comment-style` -- i.e., **javadoc**, **autodoc**, and **gtkdoc**.

I am looking for a more sophisticated means to preserve the `font-lock-comment-delimiter-face` for comment beginning/ending and preserve the `font-lock-comment-face` for everything except the function/variable that is highlighted with Yasushi's solution.

The prior solution of Yasushi is as follows:

```lisp
(require 'cc-mode)

(setq yashi-font-lock-doc-comments
  (let ((symbol "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"))
    `((,(concat "`" symbol "'")
       0 ,c-doc-markup-face-name prepend nil))
    ))

(setq yashi-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(lambda (limit)
        (c-font-lock-doc-comments "/\\*" limit
          yashi-font-lock-doc-comments)
        ))))


(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq c-doc-comment-style '((c-mode . yashi)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool. The `c-doc` system is used to highlight doxygen-style comments, which is why it changes the face from `font-lock-comment-face` to `font-lock-doc-face`.

Another drawback is that you can only have one doc style, so if you use it to highlight symbols, you can't use it for anything else.

Below is code to add a plain font-lock keyword, with the twist that the symbol must be in a comment.

```
(defun my-highlight-symbol-font-lock-keywords-matcher (limit)
  "Search for quoted symbols in comments.
Match group 0 is the entire construct, 1 the symbol."
  (let (res)
    (while
        (and (setq res (re-search-forward "`\\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\\)'" limit t))
             (not (nth 4 (syntax-ppss)))))  ; Continue, unless in a comment
    res))

(defun my-highlight-symbol-activate ()
  "Highlight symbols quoted in BACKTICK-TICK in comments."
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '((my-highlight-symbol-font-lock-keywords-matcher
                             (1 font-lock-constant-face prepend)))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'my-highlight-symbol-activate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- this achieves exactly what I was looking for.  :)

Comment: You're welcome! See you around!

Comment: You could use `(not (eql (syntax-ppss-context (syntax-ppss)) 'comment))` to make it easier to understand without a comment.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, thanks, I didn't know about this function. I agree, using it would make the code easier to read without a comment.